# Problemas no find() Cakephp

Tags: cakephp-2

Boa tarde, estou fazendo um `find()` para verificar se no período escolhido pelo usuário o recurso que ele vai usar está disponível, o único problema que eu encontrei nele foi que caso eu tenha um evento as 10:00 até as 15:00 usando um projetor dell, e outro usuário tenta criar um outro evento as 09:00 as 15:00 do mesmo dia, ele permite a criação do evento. Caso ele tente o mesmo horário ele mostra que o recurso não está disponível, ou que comece depois e termine depois funciona perfeitamente ele apenas não funciona quando o evento é antes de um já cadastrado.

```
public function getRecursosMesmaData($evento)
{
    $start = $evento['Agenda']['start'];
    $end = $evento['Agenda']['end'];

    $eventos = $this->Agenda->find('all', ['conditions' => ['OR' => ['AND' =>['Agenda.start >=' => $start,'Agenda.start <=' => $end],'AND' =>['Agenda.end >=' => $start,'Agenda.end <=' => $end],]],]);
    if ($eventos) {
        foreach ($eventos as $dado) {
            if ($dado['Agenda']['id_recurso'] == $evento['Agenda']['id_recurso']) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```